# Html/Javascript: Input Text To Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, I'm trying to search google and I can't find anything out on this.  Probably because I don't know what the technique is called.  Does anyone have any insight into how the tag input box on this website converts your text to tag items that can be removed by clicking the x?

I'm sure there is plenty of information on how to achieve this, I just don't know what it's called.

Comment: I'm not sure why 2 people have voted to close this topic without first contributing something constructive.  I don't mind if this get's closed, I just want an answer before it's closed if possible.

Comment: Why don't you just simply look at the source ? It's the better way to understand how it's make.

Comment: Were you trying to link to another website? If so your link is not working.

Comment: If a question gets closed it is because it either can't be answered or shouldn't be on this site in the first place. Either way, you shouldn't expect people voting to close a question to answer it!

Comment: @superdrac yeah that would work, I was just trying to see if there were tutorials or anything for it rather than trying to dissect source code.  Looks like I would try that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but just as a quick example without having looked at the actual code but using the CSS from the Stackoverflow tag elements - you can just retrieve the value of the input on `change()`, create an element, append the value of input and an additional element to remove the created and appended element on `click()`. As the new tag is appended and not already in the DOM when the page is loaded, you can use `on()` to delegate this `click()` event from a parent element. Instead of `document` any parent element can be used to delegate the event.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(".taginput").on("change", function () {
    var tagval = $(this).val();
    var tagelement = $("<a>");
    var remove = $("<span class='remove'>x</span>")
    $(tagelement).append(tagval).append(remove).addClass("tag");
    $("body").append(tagelement);
    $(".taginput").remove();
});
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.tag {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e4edf4;
    border: 1px solid #e4edf4;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #3e6d8e;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.remove {
    padding-left:10px;
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
}
.remove:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="taginput" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, that gives me something to go off of.  Its hard to find people who actually take time to answer questions so I appreciate it.